# GET an url or path, provided as string, in an rspec test

Tags: rspec, get

For a controller that determines the behaviour of a sidebar, I need to call several urls; the sidebar will change (a.o) based on the page on which it appears.

```
describe SidebarController do
  before(:each) do
    @sidebar = SidebarController.new
  end
  it 'should return :jobseekers for root_path' do
    get(root_url)
    @sidebar.section(root_path).should eq :jobseekers
  end
end
```

This, however, fails with `ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"sidebar", :action=>"http://test.host/"}`

Can I `get` an url or path as string? Is there a smarter way to set the `request.` data, rather then GETting it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Can I get an url or path as string?

Not in a controller test. The test controller is not actually processing a URL, it is setting up the test using one of the 5 supporting request types (get, post, put, head, delete) and then calling the appropriate controller action. See the [Guide to Testing Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#available-request-types-for-functional-tests).

What you are looking for is an integration test, or a "[request spec](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-6/dir/request-specs/request-spec)" in RSpec terms.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a workaround...in case you wanted to do this...not necessarily the best way, but a way.. this works on rails 3.2...

```
module ActionController::TestCase::Behavior
  #just parse the url and then call the regular get method
  def get_path(path)
    parsed_params = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path path
    controller = parsed_params.delete(:controller)
    action = parsed_params.delete(:action)
    get(action, parsed_params)
  end
end
```